# ClientException, and i can't print the returned value (the request body)

Tags: http, flutter, http-headers, http-post

Alright i'm losing my mind here,
in my flutter app, i'm using this function to perform post requests :

```
 Future<Map> postRequest(String serviceName, Map<String, dynamic> data) async {
    var responseBody = json.decode('{"data": "", "status": "NOK"}');
    try {
      http.Response response = await http.post(
        _urlBase + '$_serverApi$serviceName',
        body: jsonEncode(data),
      );
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        responseBody = jsonDecode(response.body);
        //
        // If we receive a new token, let's save it
        //
        if (responseBody["status"] == "TOKEN") {
          await _setMobileToken(responseBody["data"]);

          // TODO: rerun the Post request
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // An error was received
      throw new Exception("POST ERROR");
    }
    return responseBody;
  }
```

The problems are :

1. I get a ClientException (Not every time)
2. In another class, I stored the result of this function in a variable, it's supposed to return a `Future<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>`, when i printed it it shows :

   `I/flutter ( 9001): Instance of 'Future<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>'`

But when i run the same post request directly (without using a function) it worked, and it shows the message that i was waiting for.

note: in both cases (function or not), in the server side it was the same thing.

this is the function where i used the post request:

```
void _confirm() {
    if (_formKey.currentState.saveAndValidate()) {
      print(_formKey.currentState.value);
      var v = auth.postRequest("se_connecter", _formKey.currentState.value);
      print(v);
    } else {
      print(_formKey.currentState.value);
      print("validation failed");
    }
  }
```

Comment: why can't you set the headers field, are you importing the correct package?

Comment: sorry, it appears that the problem was not in the headers field, it's in the request itself.

Comment: so it is solved?if yes post an answer

Comment: When i get the ClientException, i catch it and ignore it by the debugger, then the request work, but if i use the same request directly and print the result, it shows the message that i'm waiting for, and when i use the function(which contains the same code) to do it it shows ```I/flutter ( 9001): Instance of 'Future<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>'```

Comment: sorry I can't follow with you anymore, what is your problem now, in your question you wrote 2 problems but in the comment above you say one was solved and the other is not?

Comment: The first problem ClientException happens always.

When i ignore the first problem (ignore it not solve it), i used the request directly and when i print the response body i get the message i'm waiting for. But when i used a function which contains the same request and print the response body i get this ``` I/flutter ( 9001): Instance of 'Future<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>' ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for the second problem, i just did these changes:

```
void _confirm() async {
```

and

```
var v = await auth.postRequest('se_connecter', _formKey.currentState.value);
```

and yes it is stupid.

For the exception, it was the ssl encryption that caused it, so i removed it from my backend.